# My contract will run out of gas and will not be executed. why?

Tags: solidity, transactions, ether, gas

Very very new to this.

You send 1 ether to the contract:

- It rejects it if it's not one ether exactly
- If it is, adds the address to a mapping
- If there are 5 mappings, it chooses an address at random and sends the 5 ethers, and resets the counter

Why will the contract not execute?

Thanks

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract BasicLottery {

        // A mapping to store ethereum addresses
            mapping(uint => address) public gamblers;


            uint public my_length; //*to keep track of the length.
            uint public random; //random number

            function BasicLottery(){
                my_length == 0;
            }
        // function when someone sends an ether
        // stores the address, and if there are 5 participants, 
        // chooses a winner and gives the money

        function bet() payable {

        // If the bet is not 1 ether, send the
        // money back.
        require(msg.value == 1);

        my_length +=1;

        gamblers[my_length] = msg.sender;

        if (my_length == 5) {
            // pick a random number between 1 and 5
            random = uint(block.blockhash(block.number-1))%5 + 1;
            gamblers[random].transfer(5);
            my_length == 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg.value == 1` means 1 wei is sent. You need to replace it with `msg.value == 1 ether`.

The out of gas error is probably the result of the wrong `require()`, given you are supplying a reasonable amount of gas.

Also you need to change `my_length == 0;` to `my_length = 0;`